# Connect to MySQL via PHP script tunnel

Tags: c#, php, mysql, winforms, tunnel

Here's the question, I need to connect to a remote MySQL database from my C# Application, problem is the MySQL instance will block all access to all IP's apart from localhost, this can not be changed as its too much of a security issue.

The question is, is it possible to connect via a tunnel instead to a php script hosted on the server, this would then act as the mysql connection.

Any ideas and suggestions?

Comment: So you'd have the PHP script push sql commands to the local mysql server? Sounds like a hack that will create a gaping security hole. Can't you just open up mysql to a specific set of IP's?

Comment: @LeeDavis The issue is the people using the software will be out on site at different clients each day, this would cause more of a security issue than securing a php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with going for an SSH port tunnel and achieving what I needed to do that way.

Answer (score 2):

SQLYog (a mysql management GUI utility) already has this php tunnel script with its own custom API, so if you consider writing it yourself, would be nice to have cross-support. See [Is there any good universal PHP MySQL HTTP tunnel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890170/is-there-any-good-universal-php-mysql-http-tunnel)

Comment: hmmm if I'm reading that right they pass xml to the php script to run the commands and return xml.  While that would work I could create my own API system instead, the idea is to open up mysql to raw commands without hooking into port 3306.

Comment: Well since mysql uses TCP (or sockets or pipes) as its protocol, while php is called through a HTTP web server.. you would need to run php as a daemon and thus still require some port to maintain TCP. Which is pointless.. Same questions were closed previously too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539793/tunnelling-tcp-over-http

Answer (score 0):

yes, just create a simple PHP script that will give you the desired output and use http request from the c# application to that php script to get the data - basically, you'll be building a very simple REST API (with authentication)

p.s. I don't see how that would be more secure than SSH tunnelling