# php proxy to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, proxy, shared-hosting

I want to connect HeidiSQL to my database server running on shared hosting. My shared host does not allow direct connection to the database from remote hosts - only localhost connections from php running on the shared host.

Are there are php proxies out there I can use to get around this restriction?  I would like to connect to the database with HeidiSQL with a php script acting as a transparent proxy.

This seems theoretically possible but I don't think the tool exists.

Comment: Erm, google > "HeidiSQL proxy" - I'm getting results, you should too.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890170/is-there-any-good-universal-php-mysql-http-tunnel https://gist.github.com/anonymous/410502/download#

Comment: @user985637 did you manage to make it work? Did you use the file shared as a gist?